# Left Outer Join That Returns Null Right Side In Addition To The Matching Rows

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, linq, lambda

I'm trying to make a query that will return the left outer join of two tables but with an extra row for every match that is made.  The extra rows right side being null.  Here is an example:

[image: Join]

Here is my current query using linq (responses in SQL appreciated also):

```
context.Code
       .GroupJoin(
           context.SubCode,
           code => code.CodeID,
           sub => sub.CodeID,
           (code, sub) => new
           {
               Codes = code,
               SubCodes = sub
           })
       .SelectMany(sub => sub.SubCodes.DefaultIfEmpty(),
           (code, sub) => new { Codes = code.Codes, SubCodes = sub })
       .ToList();
```

EDIT (Solution?):

```
SELECT Codes.ID, Codes.Code, SubCodes.SubCode
FROM Codes
INNER JOIN SubCodes
ON Codes.ID = SubCodes.CodeID
UNION
SELECT Codes.ID, Codes.Code, NULL
FROM Codes
ORDER BY Codes.ID
```

Comment: You could do an inner join plus a union where you just insert null for the right side.

Comment: You should use `union all` rather than `union`, because `union all` is more efficient (it does not have a duplication elimination step).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is SQL that does what you want:

```
(select c.id, c.code, sc.subCode
 from codes c join
      subcodes sc
      on c.id = sc.codeid
) union all
(select c.id, c.code, NULL
 from codes c
)
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch!  I just got it I believe.  Updated the original post.